# Only the left half of the array getting printed when splitting array in half recursively

Tags: python, recursion

Trying to implement an function that splits an array in half recursively, and here is my code

```
def mergeSort(array1, left, right):

   if left < right:

        mid = (left + right) // 2

        firstHalf = array1[left : mid]

        secondHalf = array1[mid : right] + []

        print("firstHalf is : ")
        print(firstHalf)

        print("secondHalf is")
        print(secondHalf)

        mergeSort(firstHalf, left, mid)

        mergeSort(secondHalf, mid+1, right)


nums1 = [11, 25, 13, 44, 57, 69, 17, 8, 19, 120]

low = 0

high = len(nums1)

mergeSort(nums1, low, high)
```

To my surprise, when I run the program in terminal, I only see the division from the left side getting printed out.

```
firstHalf is : 
[11, 25, 13, 44, 57]
secondHalf is
[69, 17, 8, 19, 120]
firstHalf is : 
[11, 25]
secondHalf is
[13, 44, 57]
firstHalf is : 
[11]
secondHalf is
[25]
firstHalf is : 
[]
secondHalf is
[11]
```

I don't really know why. Where is the right half?

Comment: What is `secondHalf[mid + 1]` (after you create `secondHalf`)?

Comment: Why do you think you need  `+ []`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you use offsets in the original list (`left` `right` `mid`) to slice in a much shorter list (`firstHalf`, `secondHalf`) that is already a slice from the original list. So these offsets are not correct and eventually point beyond the size of the much smaller `secondHalf` list.

Just think about it: the first time, `secondHalf` will be half the size of the original list, yet you make the second recursive call with offsets that start at `mid + 1`, which is **beyond** that size.

To correct this, either always work with the **full** list as first argument to your function, or remove the other arguments (`left`, `right`).

The first approach leads to this code:

```
def mergeSort(array1, left, right):
   if left < right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        firstHalf = array1[left : mid]
        secondHalf = array1[mid : right] + []
        print("firstHalf is : ")
        print(firstHalf)
        print("secondHalf is")
        print(secondHalf)
        mergeSort(array1, left, mid)
        mergeSort(array1, mid+1, right)


nums1 = [11, 25, 13, 44, 57, 69, 17, 8, 19, 120]
low = 0
high = len(nums1)
mergeSort(nums1, low, high)
```

The second approach leads to this code:

```
def mergeSort(array1):
   if len(array1) > 1:
        mid = len(array1) // 2
        firstHalf = array1[:mid]
        secondHalf = array1[mid:]
        print("firstHalf is : ")
        print(firstHalf)
        print("secondHalf is")
        print(secondHalf)
        mergeSort(firstHalf)
        mergeSort(secondHalf)


nums1 = [11, 25, 13, 44, 57, 69, 17, 8, 19, 120]
mergeSort(nums1)
```

Comment: how would the function look like if I decide to pass the full list as first argument?

Comment: Then it is quite trivial: just pass `array1` as first argument -- always. I inserted the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The indexes `left`, `mid`, and `right` are positions in the original list. When you split it up, you can't use the same indexes in the recursion.

There are two ways you can implement this:

1. Don't pass indexes. Slice the list and call the function recursively with each slice, until the slice is less than 2 elements long.
2. Pass the entire list in each recursive call, along with updated `low/high` indexes each time.

Comment: 2nd approach would be harder to implement

Comment: It's the way it's normally done in languages that don't have built-in list slicing, like C. It's also more efficient because you don't have to make all these copies.